# Change focus in RecyclerView in single vertical click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am building an app for Android TV by using Nested RecyclerView. Root is vertical RecyclerView which has rows with Horizontal RecyclerView.

I want to change the focus on the single click and want to keep the scroll position static. But scrolling is always happening at the bottom of the view for horizontal and vertical both.

I am using the focus listener to scroll to top

```
   verticalRLVLayout.scrollToPositionWithOffset(rowNumber,0);
   horizantalRLVLayout.scrollToPositionWithOffset(columnNumber, 0);
```

This is not working always and i don't see this is the best option.
Is there any way by which if we have fixed height of each row the single click will change the focus always.

Going upward in the RecyclerView, causes new row to slide towards right and focus goes to last visible tile on the previous row. Why this is happening, any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: can you share your whole code.  without getting in details it will not help to understand the scenario.

Comment: @animusmind If you add 5 more rows and add android:focusable="true" to card view of the rowitem on this https://github.com/thecodenest/NestedRecyclerView example , Then scroll down and after that scroll up by using the directional pad. You will while going up newly created rows scroll to right and focus goes to right side of child instead of the child which is just above the current focus  item

Comment: I would suggest if you are building for Android TV. you can better use [HorizontalGridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/widget/HorizontalGridView). This API from Leanback is having several predefined tags to use it and handle it in very easy way.